# How to create a PDF and open it using Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am currently at the end of my application and I want to export all the data I have collected from the user and put it neatly into a PDF that they then can either print or download and send off. I have tried using a couple of PDF dependencies but none seem to be web friendly. Anyone done this before and possibly point me in a good direction?

Comment: I have always used the [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) lib. I use this for a couple of web apps and a mobile app and never had any issues. Here is the demo they provide if you are curious: [Demo Site](https://davbfr.github.io/dart_pdf/#/)

Comment: I tried this one first and I could not find where it went and it never opened. Would you happen to have a quick test app I could possibly see? @PCDSandwichMan

Comment: That demo site I added includes the code for the example: [Here](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/blob/master/demo/lib/examples/resume.dart)

Comment: I have gotten it to work most of the way. Just having an issue displaying the actual pdf in a new tab. If you know of anything for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74290447/displaying-a-created-pdf-in-a-new-tab-for-flutter-web   it would be much appreciated. @PCDSandwichMan